# Understanding Amazon offerings

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am working on a project and am at a point where the POC is done and now want to move towards a real product. I am trying to understand the Amazon cloud offerings just to see if I need to be aware of them at development time. I have a bunch of questions that I cannot get answered from the Amazon site. Its probably because I am new to the whole web services thing and have never hosted a site before. I am hoping someone out here will explain this to me like I am a C programmer :)

I see amazon has a bunch of offerings -

- EC2
- Elastic Block Store
- Simple DB
- AuotScaling
- Elastic Load Balancing

I understand EC2 is virtual server instances that I can use and these could come pre-loaded with what I want (say Apache + python). I have the following questions -

- If I want a custom instance of something (like say a custom apache module I wrote for my project). Can I create a server instance using the exact modules and make it the default the next time I create a new instance or in Autoscaling?
- Do I get an IP Address to access this? Can I set my own hostname to it? I mean do I get a DNS record? Or is it what Elastic IP is?
- How do I access it from the outside? SSH? Remote Desktop? Or is it entirely up to how I configure the instance?
- What do they mean by Inter-Region or Intra-Region data transfer? What is data transfer to begin with? Is it just people using my instance? So if I go live with it that will be the cost I have to pay for people using it?
- What is the difference between AutoScaling and Elastic Load Balancing?
- What is Elastic Block Store? Is it storage? If so do I have to worry about backups or do they take care of it?

About the Simple DB -

- It looks like the interface to use this is different to my regular SQL calls. Am I correct?
- If so the whole development needs to be tailored specifically for Amazon. Which kind of sucks. Is there a better alternative?
- Do I get data backups or do I have to worry about it myself?
- Will I be able to connect to the DB using regular tools to inspect the DB (during or afte development). Or do I get other tools made by Amazon for it?
- What about security? The DB is obviously somewhere in the cloud farm away from the EC2 instance. My DB password is going over the wire and so is all my data totally unencrypted. Don't I have to worry about that? The question comes up only because I don't own any of the hardware.

I really hope some one points me in the right direction here.

Thanks for taking the time to read.

P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just went through the question and here I tried to answer few of them,
1) AWS EC2 instances doesnt publish pre-configured instances, in fact its configured by the developers and made it publicly available to the users so that they can use it. One can any one of those instances or you can just opt for what ever OS you want which is raw and provision it accordingly and create a snap shot of it so that you can use it for autos caling.The snap shot becomes the base AMI in your case.
2) Every instance you boot will have a public DNS attach to it, you can use the public DNS to connect to that instance using ssh if your are a linux user or using putty if you are a windows users. Apart from that, you can also attach a elastic IP which comes with a cost will is like peanuts and attach it to the instance and access your instance through the elastic IP and you can either map the public DNS or elastic ip to map to a website by adding a A record or Cname respectively.

3)AWS owns databases in the different parts of the world. For example you deploy your application depending upon your customer base, if you target customers are based out of India, the nearest region available is Singapore which is called as ap-southeast-1 by AWS. Each region will have multiple availability zones, example ap-southeast-1a and ap-southeast-1b, which are two different databases and geographically part. Intre region means from ap-southeast-1a to ap-southeast-1b. Inter Region means, from ap-southeast-1 to us-east-1 which is Northern Virginia Data centre. AWS charges from in coming and out going bandwidth, trust me its nothing.

They chargge 1/8th of a cent per GB. Its a thing to even think about it.

4)Elastic Load balancer is cluster which divides the load equally to all your regions across availability zones (if you are running in multi AZ) ELB sits on top the AWS EC2 instances and monitors the instance health periodically and enables auto scaling

5) To help you understand what is autoscaling please go through this document http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/

6)Elastic Block store or EBS are like hard disk which is a persistent data storage which can be attached to your instance.Regarding back up yes dependents upon your use case. I do backups of EBS periodically.

7)Simple Db now renamed as dynamo DB is nosql DB, I hope you understand what is nosql db, its a non RDMS db systems. Please read some documentation to understand what is nosql db is.

8)If you have mysql or oracle db you can opt for RDS, please read the documents.

9)I personally feel you are newbie to the entire cloud eco system, you need to understand what exactly cloud does first.

10)You dont have to make large number of changes to development as such, just make sure it works fine in your local box, it can be deployed to cloud with out much ado.

11) You dont have to use any extra tool for that, change the database end point to RDS(if your use it) or else install mysql in your ec2 instance and connect to the local db which resides in the ec2 instance and connect to it,which is as simple as your development mode.

12)You dont have to worry about any security issues aws, it is secured. Dont follow the myths, I am have been using aws since 3 years running I dont even know remember how many applications, like(e-commerce,m-commerce,social media apps) I never faced any kind of security issues and also aws allows to set your security how ever you want.

Go ahead, happy coding. Contact me if you have any problem.

Comment: I'll add to 1. that, once you have configured your instance, you can create an "AMI" with it, which is, a copy of the system, and you'll be able to start similar machines from the same "AMI".

Comment: Thanks a lot!! That answers all my questions. I do still need to understand the various DB offerings. I am new to using the cloud but understand exactly what I get from it and what to expect. Like you guessed this is the first time using it so trying to understand before jumping in.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above is a good summary on AWS. Just wanted to add

AWS offers full data center, so it depends what you are trying to achieve. For starters you will need,

- EC2 - This is your server, it comes with instance storage, which will be lost on restart
- EBS - Your mounted storage, the data is persisted across reboots
- S3  - Provides storage (RESTful API's on top, the cost is usage based rather than "provisioned" as in EBS)
- Databases - can start with Amazon RDS, which provides managed database services, you can chose between various available databases. You can also install your own database using EC2 + EBS, you will have to take care of managing the database yourself.
- Elastic IP: Public facing IP address, you can point your DNS server to this.

One great tool to calculate the pricing, 
http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/calc5.html

Comment: Thanks! Why would I need EBS and S3? with S3 will my code not be tailored specifically to the Amazon cloud? That is what confused me initially. With Amazon RDS will get automatic backups? I mean I am guaranteed that data written will not be lost right?

Comment: It depends on your application,  the difference is with what they can be used with. EBS is specifically meant for EC2 instances and is not accessible unless mounted to one. On the other hand, S3 is not limited to EC2. The files within an S3 bucket can be retrieved using HTTP protocols/BitTorrent. You will need API's (or API generated URL) to read or write information with S3. With EBS, a volume can be mounted on an EC2 and it would appear like a hard disk partition. It can be formatted with any file system and files can be written/read by the EC2 instance just like it would to a hard drive.

Comment: I understand now. Also I got this [URL](http://aws.amazon.com/running_databases/) about databases which explains clearly the different type of DB. I somehow did not find it till now.

Answer (score 0):

Some other services to take in account are:

VPC (Virtual Private Cloud). This is your own private network. You can define subnets, route tables and internet gateways there. I would strongly recommend to use VPC for any serious deployment of more than one instance.

Glacier - this will replace your tape library to storing backups.

Cloud Formation - great tool for deployment and automation of instances.